# Android Camera - Store only a part of a picture

Tags: java, android

i am fairly new to android and am currently working on a camera shooter game. any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

when taking a snapshot using an android device, would it possible to store only a part (say for example, the area on the crosshairs) rather than storing the entire picture for processing?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

May be an external library can help you out. This is cropper library which we can use to crop the images. Hope this helps

[Cropper Library](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/08/cropper/)